# A 'MultiBinding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'Setter'

Tags: c#, wpf

Title explains it I guess, I am trying to set a calculated multi binding in a template style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:MyControl}">
  <Setter Property="Width">
    <Setter.Value>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TimespanToWidth}">
         <Binding Path="RangeLength" />
         <Binding Path="TickWidth" />
      </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any solution?

EDIT:

The problem was with a custom markup extension creating the multibinding in code. I was falsely assuming that it could not be done from a

Sample code:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var b = new MultiBinding();

    b.Converter = new SimpleConverter();
    b.Bindings.Add(new Binding("A"));
    b.Bindings.Add(new Binding("B"));

    return b.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
}
```

Changed to:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var b = new MultiBinding();

    b.Converter = new SimpleConverter();
    b.Bindings.Add(new Binding("A"));
    b.Bindings.Add(new Binding("B"));

    return b;
}
```

This may be of help to others.

Comment: Can you show code of the TimespanToWidth converter? I feel that problem could be in return type...

Comment: Just testet it and it worked fine for me. What is TimeSpanToWidth?

I tested it with a simple IMultiValueConverter. But you have to make sure the return value is of type 'double'.

Do you have an error in the output window?

Comment: Sorry, I was in error, I have made a markup extension to create the multibinding for me. There was an error in this code that I called ProvideValue on the multibinding directly from the markupextension. removing that fixes the issue. (See question)